# How to print two/multiple matching lines?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, match, line

My file content is:

```
asd  
abs -5

asd 
abs 5

asd 
abs -5
```

Out of this I want to print only:

```
asd
abs -5
```

You can consider the file has got paragraph each of two lines. Out of it I need to print a paragraph which contains `abs -5` How it can be done?

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any current attempt made

Comment: I tried grep -e 'abs\|asd -5' <file_name>

Comment: Do you want to print the first hit or the last one or both? Are the trailing spaces intended?

Comment: I want to print both the lines with the space(as in abs -5)

Answer (score 0):

(This first answer is wrong)
Easy:

```
sort <filename> | uniq
```

While writing this answer I had written the question wrongly.

Next try:
What about `grep 1 "abs -5"` (By adding `1` to `grep` you mean "Don't only take the line which contains `abs -5` but also take the 1 line before and after)?  Does this help you?

Comment: `@Dominique` you can consider the file has got paragraph each of two lines. Out of it I need to print a paragraph which contains `abs -5`

Comment: @user276695: Please add this requirement to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will answer my question:

```
awk -v RS= '/asd * -5/' file
```

It's the awk's "paragraph mode".